# how to fetch nested api data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to solve this problem is, whenever user will click on category title then user will redirect to another page and will see the product_set data as per category id or slug.

i am probably new to ReactJs, it would be great if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance.

end point url: "http://localhost:8000/api/p_category"

Api data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "category01",
        "slug": "category01",
        "description": "",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/cat2_KpMV1YQ.jpg",
        "product_set": [
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/p/product01",
                "id": 1,
                "title": "product01",
                "slug": "product01",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product2_EMWEgQI.png",
                "price": 5,
                "status": true,
                "created_on": "2020-04-19T18:44:03Z"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "category03",
        "slug": "category03",
        "description": "category03 desc..",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/cat3_9dal1uP.jpg",
        "product_set": [
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/p/product03",
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product03",
                "slug": "product03",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product5.png",
                "price": 3,
                "status": true,
                "created_on": "2020-04-19T18:44:03Z"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/p/product06",
                "id": 5,
                "title": "product06",
                "slug": "product06",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product6_rkmAlce.png",
                "price": 12,
                "status": true,
                "created_on": "2020-04-19T18:44:03Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: im not getting what exactly you want to do

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you want to do above, and what you've tried in order to do it.

Comment: step 1: to fetch category data.    step 2: fetch product_set data in category data.    step 3: whenever user will click the category title then user will see the product_set data  @SohanPatil

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
import { React } from "react";

class categoryListExample extends React.Component{
    state={
        categoryList:[],
        category:''
    }

   async componentDidMount(){
        let res=await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/p_category")
        //assuming you are getting data in response.data
        this.setState({categoryList:res.data})
    }

    categoryChangeHandler=(category)=>{
        this.setState({category})
    }
    render(){
        const {categoryList,category}=this.state
        if (categoryList.length>0) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <ul>
                    {categoryList.map(category=><li key={category.id} onClick={this.categoryChangeHandler}>{category.title}</li>)}
                    </ul>
                    <CategoryComponent category={category.product_set}/>
                </div>
                )
        } else {
            return(
                <div>
                   Loading...
                </div>
                )
        }

    }
}
export default categoryListExample;
```

Comment: you can then create `CategoryComponent `

Comment: i am usually getting blank page after fetching the data

Comment: i am sharing with you my remote server id. hopefully you can help me in live server.